# uninitialized constant Tilt::CompileSite::Nokogiri error in sinatra/haml

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri

I have a two line script that works nicely in ruby. I moved it to haml and getting the error

`NameError at /
uninitialized constant Tilt::CompileSite::Nokogiri`

the haml code:

```
      %td
        - @doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file))
        = @doc.xpath("//testsuite").each_with_index {|node,index| "#{index+1}. #{node.attributes["name"].value}<BR>" }
```

any idea how I can make it work?

using below on Win XP SP3

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- nokogiri (1.4.3.1 x86-mingw32)
- sinatra (1.0)
- thin (1.2.7 x86-mswin32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still do not know why the error happens but I solved it by have a function defined in sinatra file and calling it in haml file `= get_testsuite(file)`

```
def get_testsuite (file)

  @doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file))
  output = Array.new
  @doc.xpath("//testsuite").each_with_index {|node,index|
    output << "#{index+1}. #{node.attributes["name"].value}<BR>"
  }
  return output
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%td
  - @doc = ::Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file))
  = @doc.xpath("//testsuite").each_with_index {|node,index| "#{index+1}. #{node.attributes["name"].value}<BR>" }
```

Comment: instead of `1. login 2. AddCycleTemplate 3. AddAcademicYear` on three lines I get `0 name description 0 name description 0 name description ` on one line. So the number of nodes is correct but index is always 0 and `name` is not correct either. But I do not get the initial error. Which is great. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, wasn't thinking. You don't want to render the return value of each_with_index: https://gist.github.com/e21140baeda491152510